# Use returned array to another operation

Tags: java, arrays, return

I've read a text from file into an array. I'd like to iterate through this array in another class (to reverse an array and find every 5th element). I have a problem with use this array in another class - this class cannot see array. Could anyone help me?

```
package iterators;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import iterators.*;

public class Dunno{
    int i = 1;
    String[] something() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String text = read.readLine();
        while (text != null) {
            sb.append(text);
            sb.append("\n");
            text = read.readLine();
        }
        String all = sb.toString();
        String film = all;
        String znak = ",";
        String[] tab;
        tab = film.split(znak);
        for (i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(tab[i]);
        }
        return tab;
}
}
```

And 2nd class:

```
public class Dunno1{
    Dunno dunn=new Dunno();
    dunn.something();
    public String dunn(){
    //Iterate
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you splitting using a comma (,), when you're appending a new line after each line read from the file? Shouldn't you split using "\n"?

Comment: Your second class doesn't even compile. Is that the problem? What is the exact and complete error message you get from the compiler or from java?

Comment: "<identifier> expected"
I would like to use returned array in another class; the 2nd class is only an example of use it, but I don't know, how to call this array.

Comment: I answered, despite the fact that I asked the complete and exact error message, and you only provided "<identifier> expected", which is not the complete and exact error message. This may sound pedantic, but the compiler generates errors that you should read and understand. Each of them contains the name of a file, and the line and column number of the error.

Answer (score 0):

In your second class you're calling the first class method in class scope, you're not calling it in a method or in main. Here is how you should do it:

```
public class Dunno1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Dunno1 d1 = new Dunno1();
        Dunno dunn = new Dunno();
        String[] d = dunn.something();
        d1.dunn(d);
    }

    public String dunn(String [] d) {
        return null;
        // Iterate
    }
}
```

You need to construct an object of your second class as well so that you can call the dunn method and pass it the String array you're getting from your first class (That's why the signature of the method in my answer is different).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Dunno1{
    Dunno dunn=new Dunno();
    dunn.something();
    public String dunn(){
    //Iterate
    }
}
```

The above doesn't compile, because you can't execute instructions directly inside classes. Classes must contain field declarations, constructors and methods. But not instructions.

The following would compile:

```
public class Dunno1{
    public void foo() { 
        Dunno dunn = new Dunno();
        String[] array = dunn.something();
        // iterate over the array.   
    }
}
```

This is realy basic stuff that you should learn by reading a Java book, or a tutorial. Not by asking questions on StackOverflow.